# How to show hidden pseudo-element with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, dom, pseudo-element, cssom

I'm using CSS to hide form elements:

```
#main_form #form-field-email, #form-field-realtor_select { display: none;}
#main_form .elementor-select-wrapper::before { display: none; }
```

Then JavaScript to show them with:

```
document.getElementById("form-field-first_name").onclick = function(){
document.getElementById('form-field-email').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('form-field-realtor_select').style.display = 'block';
```

The problem is with the pseudo-element `.elementor-select-wrapper::before` which is needed to hide the down arrow in the select element. I need to get the arrow to display using the JavaScript onclick event. I tried `document.getElementsByClassName()` but that did not work.

You can see the test page here: [Test Page](https://thereservemammoth.bigidearesults.com/style-sheet/). Click First Name or Last Name to reveal fields (more than listed above) and you'll see the down arrow is mission from the select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's not possible to select a pseudo element directly, but you can create a set of CSS styles like the following, which will change the `::before` element using a "toggleable" class on the parent:

```css
#main_form .elementor-select-wrapper::before {
    display: none;
}

#main_form .elementor-select-wrapper.show-chevron::before {
    display: block;
}
```

When you add (or remove) the `.show-chevron` class to `.elementor-select-wrapper`, it should toggle the `::before` element.

`document.getElementsByClassName('elementor-select-wrapper')[0].classList.add('show-chevron')`

Let me know if this works! If not, I can take another look

Comment: Hi Ross, I like your creative approach. I added the CSS and JS but the chevron does not seem to appear. Here is the test page - for on the left, click ether field: https://thereservemammoth.bigidearesults.com/style-sheet/

Comment: Hi Chris, my syntax was off, replace `.add` with `.addClass`

Comment: Hi Ross, updated JS with .addClass  - appears to be same result. See https://thereservemammoth.bigidearesults.com/style-sheet/ Let me know if I missed something. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so my syntax was off a second time, but I tested this successfully on the site. Try changing `.addClass` to `.classList.add`

Comment: Success! Thanks, Ross.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to edit the css pseudo elements via JS, as the following snippet shows.

```
    // Create a new style element
    var styleElement = document.createElement("style")
    document.head.appendChild(styleElement)

    // Get the CSSStyleSheet object of the newly created style element
    var styleSheet = styleElement.sheet

    // Add a new rule targeting the :after pseudo-element
    styleSheet.insertRule(".your-class-name:after { display: none; }", 0)
```